# Get date of next Sunday after a certain time?

Tags: php, date

I need to return the date of the next Sunday after a certain cut-off point. For example - I'm running a competition website and the cut-off is 10PM on Sunday every week, so if a user were to look at the website after 10PM on a Sunday, it would need to display next weeks date.

At the moment I'm using this:

`date('F jS', strtotime('this Sunday', strtotime(date('F jS', time()))));`

Which is great, but only works past midnight, so will only display the next Sunday's date at 00:00 on Monday, when I need it at 22:00 on Sunday.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can't your kludge it using a time zone that satisfies your requirements. Greece is GMT+2,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something simple like this suffice?

```
$competitionDeadline = new DateTime('this sunday 10PM');

$date = new DateTime();

if ($date->format('l') === 'Sunday' && $date->format('H') >= '22') {
    // It is past 10 PM on Sunday, 
    // Override next competition dates here... i.e.

    $competitionDeadline = new DateTime('next sunday 10PM');
}

// Wherever you are presenting the competition deadline...
$competitionDeadline->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Rather than using a hardcoded date, I'd construct `$competitionDeadline` as a DateTime object with 'next sunday 10PM'. Other than that, this approach looks good to me.

Comment: @Oldskool You're completely correct on that, i'll update the OP with your suggestion, ^_^

Comment: good edit.  what happens if today isn't sunday or if it is sunday and the hour is less than 22?  The readability is better than other answers though.

Comment: AS we are all getting picked up on our mistakes here today, and rightly so. This code generates the following error `Notice: Undefined variable: competitionDeadline on line 11` on any day other than Sunday after 22:00

Comment: @RiggsFolly That error would be due to me making an assumption that looking over the original post may not be correct. I assumed he had the dates for his competition pre-defined elsewhere, and only wanted this modification to run after 10 on a Sunday up till Midnight, and once we're passed that we would return to the rolling competition deadline that would be set. So the error should not happen outside the test, if other logic works as I assumed, if not then the code would need to be reworked.

Comment: @VirtualPigeon that makes sense.  I figured that's what you were doing, was just getting clarification.

Comment: @BobNocraz Ah missed your comment. I am not having the best of days today. Maybe I should go and watch some TV instead :-/

Comment: Added another minor (but important) edit in the time check to make sure the competition date gets "fast forwarded" from 22:00 onwards (rather than 23:00).

Comment: @RiggsFolly Fix away, it's a nice way for me to learn after all :p

Comment: That assumes I am now having a better day than I was earlier!

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if today is a sunday and if the hour is less than 10pm first:

```
$next = 'next'; //default to 'next', only change if below matches:
if (date('N') == '7' && date('h') < 22) $next = 'this';
```

now use that variable in your strtotime:

```
date('F jS', strtotime("$next Sunday"));
```

[3v4l proof of concept](https://3v4l.org/HbkHK)

Comment: Of course the questioner is long gone, and is not going to accept any of our now pristine answers. _Ha se la vie_ Still keeps a clean SO and thats the most important thing

Comment: @RiggsFolly at least, if they do come back, they have a few good choices =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
echo date('F jS', strtotime('this Sunday', time() + (2*60)));
```

Comment: I prefer this answer to mine, because it's so simple!  makes perfect sense when you think of sunday as the last day in the week, so adding two hours puts you into the next week (only if it's sunday >= 10pm)

Answer (score 0):

While there is a good accepted answer already for this problem, I thought it worthwhile to add the quick solution to finding the time on next Sunday at 22:00 (your original question).

The strtotime() function does the work if you add the time to the required day of the week as in:

```
$stamp = strtotime('Next Sunday + 22 hour');
echo date('D Y-m-d H:i:s', $stamp);
```

I hope that this helps someone to easily get a timestamp for a particular day and time.

Answer (score -1):

As your code returns a timestamp for next sunday @ 00:00:00 just add 22 hours to it, after checking if you are before it is already Sunday and before or after the cutoff time.

```
// work out if we what this sunday or next sunday
// based on whether we are before or after the cutoff of 22:00
$when = (date('N') == '7' && date('h') > 22) ? 'this' : 'next';

$comp_finish = strtotime("$when Sunday") + (60*60*22);
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $comp_finish);
```

Giving

```
14/02/2016 22:00:00
```

Also you dont need to use the second `strtotime` as that just generates the equivalent of `now` which is assumed by the first `strtotime` anyway

Comment: @BobNocraz Thanks for the DV, I upvoted your question as it does seem to take into account what I managed to miss i.e. the place you are if it is already a Sunday

Comment: have removed my previous comments.  i agree that it is now a working answer.  you might improve your `strtotime` line by including the time in the function: `strtotime("$when Sunday 22:00:00");`  but that is just me being picky =/

Comment: @BobNocraz Pick away, You were correct in pulling me up on a answer where I had missed a primary requirement.